# Split Comma separated Values in Column MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Here is My Resultset

```
    id  cpumanufacturer cpuseries
200014  Intel           Core i7,Core i7 Extreme Edition

200015  Intel           Core i7 Extreme Edition,Core i7

200259  Intel           Core i7 Extreme Edition,Core i7
```

I want to split cpu series to spanned across multiple rows 
like for First Row output should be

```
200014 | Intel | Core i7
200014 | Intel | Core i7 Extreme Edition
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a blog post that describes a stored procedure that will modify your table from this:

```
id     cpumanufacturer cpuseries

200014 Intel Core      i7,Core i7 Extreme Edition
200015 Intel Core      i7 Extreme Edition,Core i7
200259 Intel Core      i7 Extreme Edition,Core i7
```

To this:

```
id     cpumanufacturer cpuseries

200014 Intel           Core i7
200014 Intel           Core i7 Extreme Edition    
200015 Intel           Core i7 Extreme Edition
200015 Intel           Core i7
200259 Intel           Core i7 Extreme Edition
200259 Intel           Core i7
```

The blog post:
http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/

Keep in mind that this will modify the table, not your query results.

You may also find the following answer useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344071/1005039