# MySQL: Find similar repeated entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Given my table

```
id | name
 01| Test Name
 02| Name Test
 03| Another name
 ...
 ...
 nn| Test string
```

I'd like to do the following, for each entry, read the first word, until a space, so in this example i would read Test, then, find all similar entries which contain Test **anywhere** on the string, then continue with *Name*, *Another*, and so on.

I don't want to do this manually, as I'll have to make a **lot** of queries, the idea is the data is imported from an old excel spreadsheet and the client wants to get repeated names, so **Test Name**, **Test Something Name** and **Name Test** are potential similar names.

Comment: dont be shy to breakdown the process..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my db solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM princess a
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
        DISTINCT CASE
            WHEN name LIKE '% %' 
                THEN SUBSTR(name, 1, LOCATE(' ', name) - 1)
            ELSE name
        END AS 'name'
    FROM princess) b ON a.name LIKE CONCAT('%', b.name ,'%')
```

This will find the `DISTINCT` names (before a space) and then `JOIN` to the original table using `LIKE`.

You may also consider using `INSTR(a.name, b.name)` in place of `b.name LIKE CONCAT('%', a.name ,'%')` depending on how your `EXPLAIN` looks.

Comment: @gosukiwi You're welcome. Hopefully performance won't be an issue.

Comment: Not really, the query will be run once a while, and only by the administrator, so its fine.

Answer (score 3):

You want to run a query, select all the names, return that to php, then loop through it, parse the string into separate words, and run a query with a fulltext index.

here's something to get you started.
http://www.databasejournal.com/sqletc/article.php/1578331/Using-Fulltext-Indexes-in-MySQL---Part-1.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of examples of how to split a string into multiple rows in MySQL, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342629/mysql-split-data-into-multiple-rows).

After that, you can find the exact matches easily.  If you want non-exact matches, check out [`SOUNDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)