# Split mysql column into multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have below structure in mysql database:

```
EMAIL       PERMISSIONS
a@b         {app1: perm1; perm2; perm3};{app2: perm4; perm5; perm6}
```

I would like to use a query that will return the data in below format, in 3 columns:

```
a@b         app1        perm1
a@b         app1        perm2
a@b         app1        perm3
a@b         app2        perm4
a@b         app2        perm5
a@b         app2        perm6
```

Can be more than 3 permissions per each application.

Thank you

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: hi JS Bach, thanks for caring, the database is mariadb 10.5 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL - Split Data Into Multiple Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342629/mysql-split-data-into-multiple-rows)

Comment: hi Timothy.. I'm not allowed to use stored procedures for some reasons, that's why ideally I'll find a query to that.. Failed until now, only using substring_index seems not to sufficient, that's why I asked for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_bad_data
(email VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,permissions VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_bad_data VALUES
('a@b','{app1: perm1; perm2; perm3};{app2: perm4; perm5; perm6}');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 50
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.email
     , a.app
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.perms,';',n),';',-1) perm
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT 
              email
            , SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(permissions,'};{',n),'};{',-1),'{',''),'}',''),':',1)app 
            , SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(permissions,'};{',n),'};{',-1),'{',''),'}',''),':',-1)perms 
         FROM my_bad_data
            , cte
      ) a
   JOIN cte;
```

| email | app | perm |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a@b | app1 | perm1 |
| a@b | app2 | perm4 |
| a@b | app1 | perm2 |
| a@b | app2 | perm5 |
| a@b | app1 | perm3 |
| a@b | app2 | perm6 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tgMQ5yMZh9ryAnhAiDpjKv/0)

Comment: Wow, JS Bach... wish you all the best, thanks, it's perfect