# Split string in Mysql by colon and update a table record

Tags: mysql, string

I have created a table (Table A), which has a column (Column A) which stores values like this
Example:
`ASUNMI:GI:PI:INP:EDM:20141001:NO34W:DERERTBYDAY14:NSW
ASUNMI:GI:PI:HME:EDM:20140929:EO23M:WIERTNACAR:VICETC`

I need to split this string and place the data in different columns.

```
Example:

   Column2=ASUNMI
   Column3=GI
   Column4=PI
   Column5=INP
   Column6=EDM
```

I need to split the above string based on colons(:).the no of colons in each field could differ hence I cannot use the

```
substring_index(çolumn,':',-2) property
```

I need to then use this to update a table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673238/how-to-split-a-single-row-in-to-multiple-columns-in-mysql its been already answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a good link [please check this out](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

if you want to update TableA you can write

```
  UPDATE `TableA` SET  `columName` = (SELECT SPLIT_STR(columnName, ':',1) as ColumnName from tableName)
```

or

```
UPDATE `TableA` SET  `columName` = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(columName,':',1),':',-1) AS columName FROM tableName)
```

Comment: I am trying to use this to update a table. I am using this query but throws up an error.   update table tableA set columnname = SPLIT_STR(column)

Comment: @Programmer Please provide actual details in your answer, rather than just links to other websites.